# pip install latest dependency versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

When I install my package using `pip install -e .` it installs only unsatisfied dependencies and ignores dependency upgrades. How could I install newest dependency versions every time I run `pip install -e .`?

I have tried using `pip install --upgrade -e .`, but with this option nothing changes, I still get `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: <dependency>` notification instead of installation of the newest available version.

My `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='test_package',
    author='test',
    author_email='test@example.com',
    description='Test package',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'pyyaml',
        'requests',
    ],   
    python_requires='>=3.6'
)
```

Comment: Do you have a `requirements.txt` you run?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Nope, only `setup.py`.

Comment: You need that file for defining your required packages, and you can use it in `setup.py`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have found out, that there is an additional parameter `--upgrade-strategy` with options  `"eager"` and `"only-if-needed"`. The default is `"only-if-needed"`. Choosing the `"eager"` option forces installation of the newest available versions of the dependencies:

```
pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager -e .
```